# Obtaining string after other string

Tags: r, string, stringr, stringi

I have a `data.frame` similar to the displayed below. How can I take the 2 and 1 value previous to string `hours` and `hour` and to sum?

## Input

```
test <- data.frame(value = c('Stick 1 whole clove into center of each diamond. Roast ham 2 hours. Reduce oven temperature to 300F. Continue to roast ham until golden, about 1 hour.'))
```

## Expected output

```
> 3
```

Obs.: the numbers can be found in any string part. But every previous to `hour` or `hours`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use a regex lookaround to extract the numbers before the 'hour' with `str_extract_all`, convert it to `numeric` and get the `sum`

```
library(stringr)
sum(as.numeric(str_extract_all(test$value, "\\d+(?=\\shour)")[[1]]))
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for digits followed by space and `hour` but only capture the digits.  For each such capture convert it to numeric and then sum.  Note that only a relatively simple regex is needed and that this is vectorized and continues to work if `test` has more than one row as in second example below.

```
library(gsubfn)

sapply(strapply(as.character(test$value), "(\\d+) hour", as.numeric), sum)
## [1] 3
```

Another test:

```
test2 <- rbind(test, test)
sapply(strapply(as.character(test2$value), "(\\d+) hour", as.numeric), sum)
## [1] 3 3
```